# How to use sed to add additional field in xml line

Tags: regex, sed

I have a string like `<Phase name="ABC" hold="yes">`, I would like to it become `<Phase name="ABC" hold="yes" attr1="yes">` only if attr1 is not there.
I can program it, i just want to know if it is possible to do it with a simple sed for whole file

Answer (score 1):

sed is no the right tools for parsing XML files. If you insist then you could try this.

```
$ echo '<Phase name="ABC" hold="yes">' | sed 's/\(<Phase name="[^"]*" hold="[^"]*"\)>/\1 attr1="yes">/g'
<Phase name="ABC" hold="yes" attr1="yes">
$ echo '<Phase name="ABC" hold="yes">' | sed 's/\(<Phase name="[^"]*" hold="yes"\)>/\1 attr1="yes">/g'
<Phase name="ABC" hold="yes" attr1="yes">
```

Answer (score 0):

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) is not the right tool for this, check [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint) or [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet).

The later one can edit XML files *in-place*

Comment: Basically, I do not want to parse the xml... it is too complicated.

Comment: So install it or use perl, python, groovy or ruby and a proper XML parser.

Comment: I understand you recommend the tool, but you need provide the real code on how to work with it. Otherwise, it should be put in comments, not answer part.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '/Phase name=/ && /hold=/ {sub(/>$/," attr1=\"yes\"&")}1' file
<Phase name="ABC" hold="yes" attr1="yes">
```